# Invisible tabbar inside sliverpersistent header delegate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

I've got a tab bar inside a `SliverPersistentHeader`  delegate but I'm trying to change its color because it is transparent but it seems that every change I do to any color parameter doesn't change anything in the app, this is my code.

```dart
SliverPersistentHeader(
  //tabs
  delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
    TabBar(
      labelColor: Colors.yellow,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.yellow,
      indicatorColor: Colors.grey[800],
      tabs: [
        Tab(
            child: Text("Guardaroba",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))),
        Tab(
            child:
                Text("Post", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))),
        Tab(
            child: Text("Tagged",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  pinned: true,
),
```

And this Is my sliver app bar delegate

```dart
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

sorry if it's not right, but I tried to find documentation about delegates, but I didn't find much, so I copied the code from the internet, If anyone has a suggestion it will be very well appreciated

Comment: sorry, I had problems formatting the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `child` in this case, `TabBar` comes with `unselectedLabelStyle`.

```dart
  SliverPersistentHeader(
          //tabs
          delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
            TabBar(
              controller: controller,
              labelColor: Colors.yellow,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
              indicatorColor: Colors.grey[800],
              unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: "Guardaroba",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "Post",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "Tagged",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          pinned: true,
        ),
```

**On _SliverAppBarDelegate**

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 0,
      child: Container(
        child: _tabBar,
      ),
    );
  }
```

More about [TabBar-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html)

Comment: I tried as you said but it gives me an error, and I don't see how this could make the tabbar not invisible

Comment: you like to hide the tabbar?

Comment: no I'd like it not to overlap with my tabbarview, because now I've got a list in one of those tabs and the list overlap the tabbar as if the tabbar was invisible except for the texts

Comment: In that case, you can use `Opacity` widget. Check update answer, if it doesn't answer your question , can you include an output image you like to archive?